# Angular duplicate item via Drag & Drop

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

**Scenario**

In my current project (Angular 8) I want to add items from a source list to a target list by using the Angular CDK Drag & Drop-Module. The item should still appear inside the source list after this interaction.

**The problem**

After checking out the examples it looked pretty straightforward. Inside the `drop`-Event I've replaced `transferArrayItem()` with `copyArrayItem()`, however I want to keep the dragged item inside the source list even *while* dragging.

To provide you a simplified overview I've forked an official example by Google and changed the handling of the `drop`-Event to illustrate the issue (1).

Do you have any idea how to accomplish this behaviour?

1) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chaxhv

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chaxhv-zcfqpr) try this

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    var self=this;
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {    
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    }
    else if(event.container.id<event.previousContainer.id){
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                        event.container.data,
                        event.previousIndex,
                        event.currentIndex); 

       this.todo=this.todo.filter(function(item, pos){
                  return self.todo.indexOf(item)== pos; 
                });
    }
    else {
      copyArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                        event.container.data,
                        event.previousIndex,
                        event.currentIndex); 
     this.done=this.done.filter(function(item, pos){
              return self.done.indexOf(item)== pos; 
            });
    }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Duplicating the item via copyArrayItem() is not the issue. That's already working. The problem is that the item disappears in the source list for a short time during the dragover event in my droplist.

Comment: It seems not possible with dragging feature in this library. To solve that part ,need to create one more event to do it.

Comment: you can to have "two" list for element can be dragger and Use (cdkDragStarted) (cdkDragEnded) to change style.display to none when is dragged, some like this a bit old [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59685316/how-to-use-angulars-drag-and-drop-module-to-drag-an-element-onto-another/59698494#59698494)

Answer (score 1):

```
.cdk-drag-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Remove this css from the demo and it will be working fine you do have to use copyArrayItem

Comment: This will keep the item visible in the source list as long as the draggable is not hovering the target list. As soon as it hovers the traget list, the placeholder of source list will disappear until the mouse is released to actually drop the item to target list.